# How to insert a button in a react table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to insert a button in a react table so that the UI will be like so: [image: Ideal UI]
However, since I construct the table using the format of "tableHead" & "tableData" as shown below, seems like it is not permissible for me to add a button in the tableData array.
May I ask how should I add the button in the place as highlighted in the picture? Much appreciated.

```
             <CardBody>
              <Table
                tableHeaderColor="warning"
                tableHead={[
                  "Name",
                  "Market Value",
                  "Total Holding Value",
                  "Face Value",
                  "Maturity Date",
                  "Total Interest Received",
                  "Action",
                ]}
                tableData={[
                  [
                    "PBS17",
                    "Rp 93,000",
                    "Rp 9,300,000",
                    "Rp 1,000,000",
                    "30/6/2027",
                    "Rp 525,000",
                    "Button"
                  ],
                ]}
              />
            </CardBody>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can insert button where you are defining columns for table like below:

```
{
      width: 300,
      Header: "Button",
      Cell: ({ cell }) => (
        <button value={cell.row.values.name} onClick={props.handleClick}>
          Button
        </button>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u can pass `button` as `component` in `tableData`

```
 <CardBody>
              <Table
                tableHeaderColor="warning"
                tableHead={[
                  "Name",
                  "Market Value",
                  "Total Holding Value",
                  "Face Value",
                  "Maturity Date",
                  "Total Interest Received",
                  "Action",
                ]}
                tableData={[
                  [
                    "PBS17",
                    "Rp 93,000",
                    "Rp 9,300,000",
                    "Rp 1,000,000",
                    "30/6/2027",
                    "Rp 525,000",
                    <button></button>
                  ],
                ]}
              />
            </CardBody>
```